# Stopping robot by keyboard input

Tags: java

im trying to run a simple robot and stopping it by keyboard input.
The robot works with no problem ,but when i use the line

```
String F = Key.nextLine();
```

it stops the program from working(when i take it out the program continues to work)

why is this happening? and how to fix it? 
Is this the right way to stop a robot?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyBot {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws AWTException{

        Robot myRobot = new Robot();

        StopRobot();

        for(int i=0;i<300;i++){//the robot works just fine
            Color color = myRobot.getPixelColor(i,190);
            if((color.getRed()==0 && color.getGreen()==0 && color.getBlue()==0)){
                myRobot.mouseMove(i,190);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StopRobot() {
        Scanner Key = new Scanner(System.in);

        String F = Key.nextLine(); // this line stops my program

        if (F.equals(" "))
            System.exit(0);// 'Space' is the button to stop the program
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `nextLine` is blocking waiting for input (as expected) - what are you expecting?  Have you tried `<space><enter>` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did forget to press <enter> sorry ,but if the program does not run in the first place i dont need to stop it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to stop your method when entering space bar?

I think you have to wait when you meet a space character in a while or for statement whether your StopRobot method returns true flag or not.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyBot {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws AWTException{

        Robot myRobot = new Robot();

        while(!StopRobot())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<300;i++){//the robot works just fine
                Color color = myRobot.getPixelColor(i,190);

                if((color.getRed()==0 && color.getGreen()==0 && color.getBlue()==0)){
                    myRobot.mouseMove(i,190);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean StopRobot() {
        boolean isStop = false;
        Scanner Key = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("A"); // A prints
        String F = Key.nextLine();

        System.out.println("B"); // B does not print

        if (F.equals(" "))
        {
            System.out.println("C"); // B does not print
            //System.exit(0);// 'Space' is the button to stop the program
            isStop = true;

        }

        return isStop;
    }
}
```